# Tag [Flash-Message] seems confusing

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [flash-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-message) is mainly used for user notifications - probably because of a typo3-module and some other systems referring to notifications like that. I think the tag is misleading and should be removed in favor of [notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notifications).

The [flash-message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-message) tag does not have any explanation to make clear what it is and might also be tied to Adobe instead of notifications.

Comment: Isn't "flash message" specific to Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Well there's a lot of combinations of [tag:flash-message] with languages or frameworks